# Cannot convert excel to csv : Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: excel, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I want to convert Excel to CVS in Azure Synapse Analytics but I got an error.
The error message is "Invalid excel header with empty value".
The Excel file I want to convert looks like this (created for the question) and I need to remove the blank column A when converting to csv.
I have never used ADF before so I don't know.
Can someone please tell me how to do this?
Any help would be appreciated.
[sample.excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnZtL.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use dataflows to do that in ADF.
First create a linked service for your source data set.
Create linked service for your target folder.

My input looks like this (took from your attached sheet)

[image]

[image]

Go to the author tab of data factory and select on new dataflow.

Source settings should look like this

[image]

Source options: Point to the location where you have stored excel sheet and also select the sheetname, in my case it is sheet1 (For this example I have used Azure Blob storage)

[image]

Keep rest of the tabs as default and add a sink to your data flow.

Sink Settings should look like below

[image]

Point to the target location where you want to store your csv file (I have used Azure blob storage). Keep rest of the things on default

[image]

Go to the new pipeline and pull dataflow activity in your canvas and trigger your dataflow.

[image]

And my output in csv looks like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I have a question.
Q. Why did you select "Inline" source type? Why not an integrated dataset?

Comment: You can also use an integrated dataset with copy activity even easier way of doing it; I tried with both ways and got the same result.